# Updating Xfce in Linux Mint beyond the standard version

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, xfce, software-updates

I'm running Linux Mint 20 Xfce and would like to update Xfce to the latest version (beyond the version offered in the Mint repos). Is there a PPA or something for this, and is it likely to cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

You are not running rolling release Linux distributive. Linux Mint has own release cycles, after a new release they update all system components and packages at once.

It's usually not a good practice to update components like an entire Desktop Environment (DE, which is Xfce) without an upgrading distro entirely to the new major version.

Linux packages are depend on each other, so updating a part from PPA could usually lead to unexpected bugs.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case, but just had a feeling I had done this successfully in the past. Not a huge deal though - maybe time to update the whole system anyway.

Comment: @Sam you could try to pin newer Xfce packages from testing repos with Apt Pinning, but in case of Xfce it could update almost entire system after `sudo apt upgrade` (because packages depend on each other as I said) and even break.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. I think I'll just play it safe and avoid messing things up!